# Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable<model> for method xx

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

I have very new to rxJava and I'd like to chain 2 api call in sequence together using Retrofit. But keep getting this error: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable for method xx. Below are part of my codes:

```
            ServiceA
            .subscribeOn(rx.schedulers.Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(new Func1<ResponseA, Observable<ResponseB>>() {
                @Override
                public rx.Observable<ResponseB> call(ResponseA fooA) {
                    // code to save data from service A to db

                    // call service B
                    return ServiceB;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseB>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ResponseB fooB) {
                    // code to save data from service B to db

                }
            });


 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("xxx")
                  .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();


compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'   
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Comment: You have the wrong RxJava - Retrofit adapter version pairing. Either use RxJava 2 or use `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory`. https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2

Comment: Are you saying I should use this instead? 
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'

Comment: Always use the latest: `'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.16'`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this

```
    val loginRequest = retrofitService.login(params)
loginRequest
        .flatMap { response ->
            saveLoginInfo(response.data)
            return@flatMap retrofitService.getProfile(params) }
        .flatMap { response ->
            doSomethingWithProfile(response.data)
            return@flatMap retrofitService.getItems(params) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe (
            { response ->
                doSomethingWithItems(response.data)
                doSomethingInMainThread()
            },
            { err -> Log.v("TAG", err.localizedMessage) },
            { Log.v("TAG", "Chains Completed") }
        )
```

Check more in the [link](https://medium.com/@adinugroho/chaining-multiple-retrofit-call-using-rxjava-177b64c8103e)